# changing button text according to its id?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Here is the code

```
bt1 = Button(root, text=" ", height=3, width=3, command=lambda:OnButtonClick(1))
bt2 = Button(root, text=" ", height=3, width=3, command=lambda:OnButtonClick(2))
bt3 = Button(root, text=" ", height=3, width=3, command=lambda:OnButtonClick(3))
bt4 = Button(root, text=" ", height=3, width=3, command=lambda:OnButtonClick(4))
bt5 = Button(root, text=" ", height=3, width=3, command=lambda:OnButtonClick(5))
bt6 = Button(root, text=" ", height=3, width=3, command=lambda:OnButtonClick(6))
bt7 = Button(root, text=" ", height=3, width=3, command=lambda:OnButtonClick(7))
bt8 = Button(root, text=" ", height=3, width=3, command=lambda:OnButtonClick(8))
bt9 = Button(root, text=" ", height=3, width=3, command=lambda:OnButtonClick(9))
```

I want to change the button text depending upon which button in pressed, I know its possible using if else statement but isn't there any efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I have understood correctly, but are you after something like this?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

def OnButtonClick(button_number):
    widget = button_list[button_number-1]
    widget.config(text='Got pressed')

bt1 = Button(root, text=" ", command=lambda:OnButtonClick(1))
bt1.pack()
bt2 = Button(root, text=" ", command=lambda:OnButtonClick(2))
bt2.pack()

button_list = [bt1, bt2]
```